# Mountain Lion Zend Install - You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

Tags: zend-framework, ssl, installation, composer-php

I've been trying to get Zend installed on my Mac Pro for some time.  I've tried installing it manually, with homebrew, and with port.  I've changed php's, reinstalled php, updated php, reinstalled openssl multiple times.

php.ini has openssl in it and it is uncommented, curl is also enabled.

no matter which way I go about it I always get a message like this or very similar (always ssl)

> You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

I also installed a certificate for ssl.

currently I have downloaded the zip for the Zend 2.2.2 'tutorial', extracted to a sites directory and have run

> composer install

which as given me:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) 
   - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.2.2)
                                                            
  [RuntimeException]                                                 
  You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https   

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
```

I know its installed.  I've reinstalled it 3 times.  Only thing I can think of is maybe there is more than one php.ini  but I haven't been able to find a second one.

thanks in advance for any advice.

I ran php info in apache and got the old install of php version 5.3, when I run it from the command line I get the new 5.4  ?

> $ openssl version
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
>
> $ composer diag
>
> Checking platform settings: FAIL
>
> The openssl extension is missing, which will reduce the security and stability of Composer.
>
> If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
>
> Checking http connectivity: OK
>
> Checking composer.json: OK
>
> Checking disk free space: OK
>
> Checking composer version: OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to say there was an easy fix.  My suggestion is to use homebrew, install everything, then make sure your php.ini is in the right spot (probably have to move it) and also that you change the permissions on local\openssl so that homebrew can write to it.  Eventually by moving php.ini around and installing php54 I was able to get it to work.

these are great resources

http://juniorgrossi.com/2013/working-with-multiple-php-versions-on-mac-os-x/

http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one php.ini - the command line version of PHP has a separate one. To see what that is, run `php -i | grep ini` from the command line - the output should include the .ini files being used near the top.

(Disclaimer: I'm not a Mac user so things may be different in Apple world.)

Comment: I did this and it told me /usr/local/lib was where the php.ini was, but when I go there, there is no php.ini in that folder.  there is php folder and when i go in there I don't see a php.ini either.  thanks, this might get me some more options!